# How to know when to use ./ or not?

Tags: command-line, directory

I am watching some tutorials on how to navigate the filesystem but no matter which tutorial I watch there is one thing that no one seems to answer.

I understand that `.` is current directory. I understand that `/` is either root directory or it can just mean the end of a current directory.

So how come if I want to run a program in the current directory I have to do `./ProgramName`? Is this just because `ProgramName` could be in `$PATH` and I have to specify that I want to run the version in the current directory? Why doesn't Ubuntu automatically run the current directory's version if there's no equivalent in `$PATH`?

And if so why am I allowed to omit `./` when I am traversing directories? For example I can just do `cd DropBox` from my home directory. I can also do `cd ./DropBox` and it seems to work but why isn't the `./` required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me try to explain it, to answer the `cd` situation. Now we have `.` -- `current directory`, then `/` -- `root` directory, now remember that the `/` is used in Linux to indicate `absolute path` and not relative path, when it starts the path address. Now in your case;

1. When you use `cd folder_name` you are using the `relative path` address to that (current) directory so no need to specify the path, your already in there.
2. When you use `cd ./folder_name` it says move me into the folder with name `folder_name` in the current (`.`) directory.
3. You run a program in current directory `.`, with `./program.sh` says -- `don't bother searching in the standard paths` look in the current `.` folder. This is standard Linux setup.
4. In addition (thanks to Sergiy), other thing that I would add is that when using `globstar` to deal with files one should use `./` because it is safer. Say you run something like `ls *`, and you have filename like `-231.txt`. The ls command will think that `-2` is a command switch, but there's on switch like that on ls , so you'll get an error. With `ls ./*` it will work without problems. So, `./` is used not only for `cd` somewhere or running script

Comment: So `cd folder_name` and `cd ./folder_name` are the same right?

Comment: Yes there are the same thing!

Comment: Very nice answer. One other thing that I would add is that when using globstar to deal with files one should use ./ because it is safer. Say you run something like `ls *`, and you have filename like `-231.txt`.  The `ls` command will think that -2 is a command switch, but there's on switch like that on `ls` , so you'll get an error. With `ls ./*` it will work without problems. So, ./ is used not only for cd somewhere or running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

When you use cd, it specifically means that you want to change the directory hence the OS will look into children of the current directory. 
When running a program, './' clears that it is a program and not a command.